# Information containable in a volume depends on surface area, but a volume of space can contain a volume with a bigger surface area?

Tags: quantum-information, information, holographic-principle

The holographic principle has me confused. I'm wondering, if a volume can contain more information if it has a larger surface area, how can it be that a volume with a bigger surface area can be contained in a volume with a smaller surface area?

Example: take the shape of a star symbol and extend it into the third dimension. Think of a box that touches the prongs of the star on each of it's sides. The box has a smaller surface area, but it contains the star.

Does that mean a part of a volume can have the ability to contain more information, the volume it self?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A general version of the holographic principle is introduced in Bousso (1999) [A covariant entropy conjecture](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9905177). In the simplest case of an isolated black hole, it reduces to an earlier version of the principle, which says this:

- The entropy (the natural log of the number of microstates compatible with that black hole macrostate, in a theory of quantum gravity) is given by $Ac^3/4G\hbar$, where $A$ is the area of the event horizon, $c$ is the speed of light, $G$ is Newton's gravitational constant, and $\hbar$ is Planck's constant.

Intuitively, since any attempt to cram more information-carrying stuff into that region will just make the black hole even bigger, this principle implies an *upper bound* on the amount of information (as quantified by the entropy) that can be encoded inside any spherical region with surface area $A$.

Regardless of the precise formulation, the key point here is that in ordinary circumstances (without black holes), the holographic principle only gives an *upper bound* on how much information can be encoded within a given region. If a region with surface area $A$ is contained within a larger-volume region with smaller surface area $a<A$, as described in the OP, then the amount of information in the smaller-volume region cannot exceed $ac^3/4G\hbar$, even though its surface area is larger than $a$. This is just like saying if $x\leq 7$ and $x\leq 3$, then $x$ can't be any bigger than $3$.

Comment: thanks, now that makes sense